# Having trouble compiling the Twilio C++ libraries

Tags: c++, makefile, twilio

Compiling the C++ API for Twilio. The instructions by Laurent Luce are not very clear and were done two years ago.

HOW exactly do I use libcurl and openssl with make (nmake) to compile the library???? When I try to run nmake on the command line in the twilio++ directory, I get:

> makefile(25) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '^'
>   in macro Stop.

If anyone can help or give directions I would be very relieved

Answer (score 0):

If this error is caused by `$^`. you may try to replace it with `$**`. But no guarantees. In general, `nmake` does not work with GNU makefiles. For best results use GNU `make`.

Comment: Thanks. It was not caused by $^, I dont think, but I've stopped using make and am now trying to use cl.exe and csc.exe directly from command line (small files, v. small project). I have problems with this, but I'll probably search(ask) another question. Thanks again.